# Is $(1-\Delta)^{-s}$ bounded on weak $L^p$ spaces?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

Let $p \in [1,\infty]$.
It is well-known that $(1-\Delta)^{-s}:= \mathcal{F}^{-1}(1+|\xi|^2)\mathcal{F}$ is a bounded linear operator from $L^p(\mathbb{R}^d)$ to itself when $s >0$.
I wonder if $(1-\Delta)^{-s}$ is bounded on $L^{p,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^d)$, where $L^{p,\infty}$ is the weak $L^p$ space when $s > 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $G_{\alpha}(\cdot)=\mathcal{F}^{-1}\left((1+|\xi|^{2})^{-\alpha/2}\right)(\cdot)$, $\alpha>0$, so you want to show that
\begin{align*}
\|G_{\alpha}\ast f\|_{L^{p,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}\lesssim\|f\|_{L^{p,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}.
\end{align*}
This follows by the more general Young's inequality that
\begin{align*}
\|f\ast g\|_{L^{r}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}\lesssim\|f\|_{L^{p,\infty}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}\|g\|_{L^{q}(\mathbb{R}^{n})}
\end{align*}
for $1<p,q,r<\infty$ such that
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{r}+1=\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}.
\end{align*}
Let $r=p$ and $q=1$. Use the fact that $G_{\alpha}\in L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$, then you are done.

Comment: The translations $T_af(x)= f(x-a)$ are isometries in any $L^{p,\infty}.$ Therefore the convolution operator with $L^1$ function $\varphi$  is bounded by $\|\varphi\|_1.$

Comment: Hmm... I just made things too complicated, thanks for pointing out.